# Extracting .jar files to a directory, adding new files, then repacking into a .jar file in java

Tags: java, installation, minecraft

I was wondering whether there is a way to take a given .jar file, selected with a JFileChooser, extract it and put it into a new directory. Then, take all the files from another directory, add it to the directory with the extracted .jar file, and then take all that and package it back up again.

I'm doing this because I want a really easy way to install mods for that game, minecraft, where you can just select your minecraft.jar, and make sure the files for the mod are in a folder, and wait a bit, as indicated by a JProgressBar.

This is all I have so far

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.jar.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        super("Auto-mod installer");
        setSize(300, 60);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JProgressBar bar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        add(bar);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
    }

    private void extract(File f) {
        //Hrm...
    }

    private void addModFiles() {
        //Uh...
    }

    private void repackage(File f) {
        //What?
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have no idea what I'm doing. I do know what the imports needed are, but that's about it. Help would be appreciated, ranting about anything I did wrong would get me mad. Thanks!

EDIT: If you know a way to get the same results, and it's not the way that I was looking for, please let me know how to do so. As long as I get the results I was looking for, it would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: I expect you won't be able to change this in a jar file that is loaded for your application.  Why not show some attempt to extract and copy the files over, as that should be simple.

Comment: @JamesBlack anything that would get me a .jar packaged again with the files I wanted in it would be awesome

Comment: The easiest way to call the 'jar' command, and use -u if you are placing and I think -a might be for adding.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is relatively simple. You have a few gotchas (like what to do if files already exist and that kind of thing), but otherwise...

I'd start by having a look at [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html)

(I'm in the middle of another example, but when I get time, I'll post some stuff)

**UPDATE with Example**

```
public class JarTest {

    protected static final String OUTPUT_PATH = "..."; // The place you want to extact the jar to

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new JarTest();

    }

    public JarTest() {

        try {

            unjar();
            // Copy new contents in...
            jar();

        } catch (IOException exp) {

            exp.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    // This just recursivly lists through all the files to be included in the new jar
    // We don't care about the directories, as we will create them from the file
    // references in the Jar ourselves
    protected List<File> getFiles(File path) {

        List<File> lstFiles = new ArrayList<File>(25);

        // If you want the directories, add the "path" to the list now...

        File[] files = path.listFiles();
        if (files != null && files.length > 0) {

            for (File file : files) {

                if (file.isDirectory()) {

                    lstFiles.addAll(getFiles(file));

                } else {

                    lstFiles.add(file);

                }

            }

        }


        return lstFiles;

    }

    // Re-Jar the contents
    // You should always attempt to jar back to a new file, as you may not want to effect the original ;)
    public void jar() throws IOException {

        JarOutputStream jos = null;

        try {

            String outputPath = OUTPUT_PATH;

            // Create a new JarOutputStream to the file you want to create
            jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("...")); // Add your file reference

            List<File> fileList = getFiles(new File(OUTPUT_PATH));
            System.out.println("Jaring " + fileList.size() + " files");

            // Okay, I cheat.  I make a list of all the paths already added to the Jar only create
            // them when I need to.  You could use "file.isDirectory", but that would mean you would need
            // to ensure that the files were sorted to allow all the directories to be first
            // or make sure that the directory reference is added to the start of each recursion list
            List<String> lstPaths = new ArrayList<String>(25);
            for (File file : fileList) {

                // Replace the Windows file seperator
                // We only want the path to this element
                String path = file.getParent().replace("\\", "/");
                // Get the name of the file
                String name = file.getName();

                // Remove the output path from the start of the path
                path = path.substring(outputPath.length());
                // Remove the leading slash if it exists
                if (path.startsWith("/")) {

                    path = path.substring(1);

                }

                // Add the path path reference to the Jar
                // A JarEntry is considered to be a directory if it ends with "/"
                if (path.length() > 0) {

                    // At the trailing path seperator
                    path += "/";

                    // Check to see if we've already added it out not
                    if (!lstPaths.contains(path)) {

                        // At the path entry...we need need this to make it easier to 
                        // extract the files at a later state. There is a way to cheat,
                        // but I'll let you figure it out
                        JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(path);
                        jos.putNextEntry(entry);
                        jos.closeEntry();

                        // Make sure we don't try to add the same path entry again
                        lstPaths.add(path);

                    }

                }

                System.out.println("Adding " + path + name);

                // Create the actual entry for this file
                JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(path + name);
                jos.putNextEntry(entry);

                // Write the entry to the file
                FileInputStream fis = null;
                try {

                    fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    while ((bytesRead = fis.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {

                        jos.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

                    }

                    jos.flush();

                } finally {

                    try {
                        fis.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }

                jos.closeEntry();

            }

            jos.flush();

        } finally {

            try {
                jos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }

    }

    public void unjar() throws IOException {

        JarFile jarFile = null;

        try {

            String outputPath = OUTPUT_PATH;
            File outputPathFile = new File(outputPath);
            // Make the output directories.
            // I'll leave it up to you to decide how best to deal with existing content ;)
            outputPathFile.mkdirs();

            // Create a new JarFile reference
            jarFile = new JarFile(new File("C:/hold/Java_Harmony.jar"));

            // Get a list of all the entries
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {

                // Get the next entry
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                // Make a file reference
                File path = new File(outputPath + File.separator + entry.getName());
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {

                    // Make the directory structure if we can
                    if (!path.exists() && !path.mkdirs()) {

                        throw new IOException("Failed to create output path " + path);

                    }

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Extracting " + path);

                    // Extract the file from the Jar and write it to disk
                    InputStream is = null;
                    OutputStream os = null;
                    try {

                        is = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
                        os = new FileOutputStream(path);

                        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead = -1;
                        while ((bytesRead = is.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {

                            os.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        }

                        os.flush();

                    } finally {

                        try {
                            os.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        } finally {

            try {
                jarFile.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful, but I'm not on java 7. I use java 6, and I don't really have time to relearn some syntax.

Comment: The method is the same for both Java 7 & 6

Comment: @The_Steve13 now with an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use this very simple library to **pack/unpack jar file**

[JarManager](https://bitbucket.org/ReaperSoon/maven-repo/src/367c0bcb2749/fr/stevecohen/jarmanager)

Very simple

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import fr.stevecohen.jarmanager.JarPacker;
import fr.stevecohen.jarmanager.JarUnpacker;

public class MyClass {

    public void addFileToJar(String jarPath, String otherFilePath) {
        try {
            JarUnpacker jarUnpacker = new JarUnpacker();
            File myJar = new File("./myfile.jar");
            File otherFile = new File(otherFilePath);

            Path unpackDir = Files.createTempDirectory(myJar.getName()); //create a temp directory to extract your jar
            System.out.println("Unpacking in " + unpackDir.toString());
            jarUnpacker.unpack(jarPath, unpackDir.toString()); //extraxt all files contained in the jar in temp directory

            Files.copy(otherFile.toPath(), new File(unpackDir.toFile(), otherFile.getName()).toPath()); //copy your file

            JarPacker jarRepacker = new JarPacker();
            File newJar = new File("./maNewFile.jar");
            System.out.println("Packing jar in " + newJar.getAbsolutePath());
            jarRepacker.pack(unpackDir.toString(), newJar.getAbsolutePath()); //repack the jar with the new files inside
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use **maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.stevecohen.jarmanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>JarManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You also need my repository

```
<repository>
    <id>repo-reapersoon</id>
    <name>ReaperSoon's repo</name>
    <url>http://repo-maven.stevecohen.fr</url>
</repository>
```

Check the last version with the link bellow to use the last dependency

Please use my [public issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ReaperSoon/maven-repo/issues) if you find some bugs